# Quarkus application is failing with message Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException:

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am trying to develop a simple Quarkus wrapper application to my Java based application `Project-A`. I am able to create the application but when I run  the command `mvn clean install` then I am getting the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.9.2.Final:build (default) on project project-a-service: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.amazon.common.deployment.AmazonServicesClientsProcessor#setup threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Missing 'software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client' dependency on the classpath
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.amazon.common.deployment.AmazonServicesClientsProcessor.missingDependencyException(AmazonServicesClientsProcessor.java:171)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.amazon.common.deployment.AmazonServicesClientsProcessor.setup(AmazonServicesClientsProcessor.java:120)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:925)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[ERROR]         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I tried adding the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>url-connection-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.17.224</version>
</dependency>
```

But still its not working for me. Can someone please let me know why am I getting this issue and how can I fix this please?

Comment: Why did you set the scope to test? Quarkus needs it to build (and run).

Comment: @RobSpoor Thanks a lot for the response. I tried removing `test` and re-ran again but still the same issue. Can you please tell me what can I try different?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Without a scope the dependency should be included and part of the class path during the build. I've worked on Quarkus application with several dependencies, and I've never seen this error before.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same error and was not able to solve it with lates quarkus 2.10.2.
Worked around using the direkt dependency of the AWS SDK and not the quarkus dependency. In my case the service was SQS.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqs</artifactId>
  <version>2.17.229</version>
</dependency>
```